# Remove or replace matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy

Hi i have this matrix

e.g

```
import numpy as np
a= np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)

[[1. 2. 3. ]
 [4. 5. 6. ]
 [7. 8. 9. ]]
```

how do i delete the bottomost value of a selected col (e.g col = 1) and the rest of the values on top gets pushed down, and if there is an empty space, put "0"

so the matrix becomes

```
[[1. 0. 3. ]
 [4. 2. 6. ]
 [7. 5. 9. ]]
```

Comment: a= np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3) this provides a matrix starting with 0

Answer (score 1):

Roll the second column and then set the first element of the column to zero

```py
a = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3, 3)

a[:, 1] = np.roll(a[:, 1], 1)
a[0, 1] = 0

print(a)
```

Output:

```py
[[1 0 3]
 [4 2 6]
 [7 5 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you may use `np.pad` here:

E.g.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a= np.arange(1, 10).reshape(3, 3)
>>> print a
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
>>> a[:,1] = np.pad(a[:,1], pad_width=1, mode='constant')[:a.shape[1]]
>>> print a
[[1 0 3]
 [4 2 6]
 [7 5 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [215]: a = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
```

Make a temporary array to hold the new column's values:

```
In [216]: temp = np.zeros(a.shape[0],a.dtype)                                   
In [217]: temp[1:] = a[:-1,1]
```

copy that into `a`:

```
In [218]: a[:,1] = temp                                                         
In [219]: a                                                                     
Out[219]: 
array([[1, 0, 3],
       [4, 2, 6],
       [7, 5, 9]])
```